# GDAL Reproject & Scale to 8bit simultaneously

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to create a pipeline to process 16bit panchromatic imagery by making sure they're in a specified projection and scaled to 8 bit. It seems that gdal.Warp doesn't/isn't able to handle the scaling and gdal.Translate can't do the reprojection. On top of this, it seems that my scaling to 8bit using the python wrapper isn't quite working like the cli gdal_translate. I'm trying to limit i/o of images, any suggestions on how to approach accomplishing both tasks simultaneously?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import pyproj

def process_16bit_pan(in_image, dst_crs):

    image_name = os.path.basename(in_image)

    out_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(in_image), 'processed')
    
    os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    out_image = os.path.join(out_dir, image_name)
    
    warp = gdal.Warp(out_image, in_image, dstSRS=validate_crs(dst_crs), creationOptions=['COMPRESS=None'])
    warp = None

    scale = gdal.Translate(out_image, out_image, outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, scaleParams=[[0,65535,0,255]])
    scale = None

def validate_crs(input_crs):
    if not isinstance(input_crs, pyproj.CRS) and input_crs is not None:
        out_crs = pyproj.CRS(input_crs)
    else:
        out_crs = input_crs

    return out_crs
```

Comment: Have you tried to write the result of gdal.Warp into a VRT file? That should at least limit i/o.

Comment: I hadn't but that is a good idea and solves the i/o piece. I guess there is no way around having to warp then translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I've seen there doesn't seem to be a really good way to handle reprojection and scaling simultaneously with the same command, so I'm using an in memory file to do the reprojection with `gdal.Warp()` then passing the in memory file to `gdal.Translate()` and writing that file to disk.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import pyproj
import shutil

def process_16bit_pan(in_image, dst_crs, overwrite=False):

    image_name = os.path.basename(in_image)

    out_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(in_image), 'processed')
    
    os.makedirs(out_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    in_mem = f"/vsimem/in_memory_{image_name}.tif"
    warp = gdal.Warp(in_mem, in_image, dstSRS=validate_crs(dst_crs), creationOptions=['COMPRESS=None'])
    warp = None

    scaled_image = os.path.join(out_dir, image_name)

    scale = gdal.Translate(scaled_image, in_mem, outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, scaleParams=[[0, 65535, 0, 255]])
    scale = None
    
    if overwrite:
        print("Overwriting original files...")
        shutil.move(scaled_image, in_image)
        shutil.rmtree(out_dir)

def validate_crs(input_crs):
    if not isinstance(input_crs, pyproj.CRS) and input_crs is not None:
        out_crs = pyproj.CRS(input_crs)
    else:
        out_crs = input_crs

    return out_crs
```